# Store different rows type in single table

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite, architecture

I'd like to create a DB to store different rows type. It will be kind of event list with time stamp. So I'd like to have an `Event` table with relations to other tables - each table will be a row type (`Transition`, `Position`, `Error`):
[image]

**Is this a good approach?** Possible drawbacks:

- as a result I'll have to take care that every row in `Event` exactly 1 FK `not null` as it can relate to exactly 1 event
- when adding new event type I'll have to upgrade* `Event`
- when I'll have many event types the result will be that a row in `Event` table will have mostly `null` columns and only 1 will be `not null`

*EDIT: `Transition`, `Position`, `Error`, `Location` tables has unique columns which are not put in the image above, e.g. `Transition` has `type`, `Position` has 'latitude'/'longitude', `Error` has `payload` etc.*

* By upgrade, I mean when I need to add new type to Event table I'll require rewrite whole Event table - as I'm working on Android it'll require using method SQLiteOpenHelper->onUpgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You have it the other way round.

Put EventId and EventName on Event table and reference EventId in other tables. In other words,

1. **Add EventId** column in Transition, Position and Error tables.
2. **Remove time_stamp, transition_id, position_id, and error_id** from the Event table.

Comment: But then all unique columns from tables Transition, Position and Error should be in Event table. This is not what I want.

Comment: Why would all unique columns from tables Transition, Position and Error should be in Event table?